# query about one php function

Tags: php

what does this function means

```
function entre2v2($text,$marqueurDebutLien,$marqueurFinLien)

{

$ar0=explode($marqueurDebutLien, $text);
$ar1=explode($marqueurFinLien, $ar0[1]);
$ar=trim($ar1[0]);
return $ar;
}
```

in above code $text refers to a text files content,which is obtained by the following code from a form post:

```
$text=file_get_contents($_POST['file']);
```

can anybody please describe about the mentioned php function?i dont understand what these two variable means

```
$marqueurFinLien
$marqueurDebutLien
```

according to first answer,I tried .But it shows error.

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for entre2v2(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 5 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: marqueurFinLien in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 18

Warning: explode() [function.explode]: Empty delimiter in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 18
```

when I used the follwing:

```
<?

$text=file_get_contents('http://localhost/php/w.txt');

$name=entre2v2($text,"DB_USER', ',');");


echo($name);
echo("<br>");



function entre2v2($text,$marqueurDebutLien,$marqueurFinLien)

{

$ar0=explode($marqueurDebutLien, $text);
$ar1=explode($marqueurFinLien, $ar0[1]);
$ar=trim($ar1[0]);
return $ar;
}

?>
```

Comment: $firstLinkMarker and $lastLinkMarker if that helps...

Comment: I want to point out this particular line of code: 

`file_get_contents($_POST['file']);`

This could be easily exploited by sending a POST http request to this web file and passing in a file path to say, something in your operating system for instance. Remember kids: Always sanitize user-generated inputs, don't trust it!

Comment: `($text,"DB_USER', ',');");` => `($text, 'DB_USER', ',');`. You're sending a single string here, and it expects two delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function appears to return the text between the `$marqueurDebutLien` and `$marqueurFinLien` strings from the input `$text`.

e.g.

```
$text = "abcdefghijklmnop";
$result = entre2v2($text, 'd', 'lmn'); // will return 'efghijk'
```

Comment: what does this two function means?

$marqueurFinLien
$marqueurDebutLien

Comment: See my original comment on your question. It doesn't really matter what they're called though....they could be called $banana and $badger for all the difference it would make. What matters is what they're doing, which I tried to make clear.

Comment: thnx for making me clear.could u please tell,what does this part means

$ar0=explode($marqueurDebutLien, $text);
$ar1=explode($marqueurFinLien, $ar0[1]);
$ar=trim($ar1[0]);
return $ar;

i am noob at php.i have just started working on it.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it looks like a way to parse a string - very inefficient and fragile, may I say.

```
$ar0 = explode($marqueurDebutLien, $text);
```

This line will break ('explode') a string stored in $text into array of substrings, using a `$marqueurDebutLien` string as a separator. Then it takes the *second* element of this array (i.e., what follows `$marqueurDebutLien`) and break it once more:

```
$ar1 = explode($marqueurFinLien, $ar0[1]);
```

... now using `$marqueurFinLien` as a separator.

The first element of this array is, by definition, the first string that lies in the original string (`$text`) between `$marqueurDebutLien` and `$marqueurFinLien` 'marker substrings'. Its trimmed version is what function returns.

Why inefficient, you may ask? There are actually several small things that could be quite easily improved here: limits for `explode`s, so only a small part would be processed, returning result of `trim` right away instead of storing it in some variable...

But in fact, the whole approach is flawed. Look at this:

```
function notSoMysticEntre2v2($text, $openingDelimiter, $closingDelimiter) {
   $mark1 = strpos($text, $openingDelimiter);
   if ($mark1 === FALSE) { 
       return null; 
   }  
   $mark2 = strpos($text, $closingDelimiter, $mark1);
   if ($mark2 === FALSE) {
       return null;
   }
   $data  = substr($text, $mark1 + 1, $mark2 - $mark1 - 1);
   return trim($data);
}
```

Take note that this function is quite more fool-proof than the first one: it will correctly fail to parse the string (returning `null` as a sign of error) if there's no opening delimiter there OR if it's not followed by closing delimiter.

Comment: I knew that this answer will take too long to be written, but just can't help writing it, when looking at the original code. ) And, of course, if these delimiters are actually just characters, it's far more easier (and faster) using `strtok`.